# What Pagan Min discuss with Yuma on the phone?

Tags: far-cry-4

It's been bugging me, at the Pagan Min Palace, at the beginning of the game, when the player have a dinner, pagan told the player to stay right here and enjoy the soup rangoon, he said he will be right back. After that he said "Yuma, We need to talk". At that moment if we stay right where we are, we will get an "alternate ending". But it took about 20-30 minutes to trigger this ending. I wonder what Pagan min discuss with Yuma, because it took a lot of time... Does anyone know what pagan min discussed with Yuma ?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an actual recorded dialog of the conversation in the game.  May not be possible to answer this one.